# Tkinter scrollbar resets to initial position

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I've attached a scrollbar to a list box. When I click and drag it, it scrolls fine however just as I release the mouse the scrollbar jumps back to the top. Is there a way I can stop this from happening?

I orient scrollbar as Vertical and attach it to the yview of my list box(by setting `scrollbar.config(command = listBox.yview)`). Then I pack it to side = RIGHT and fill = Y.
I don't modify it at all after this. Can you help me figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also configure your listbox to control the scrollbar. Effbot has good info [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm). Do:

```
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```